# How to run this command SSJS

Tags: tooltip, xpages

[tooltipScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWg5G.png)
`XSP.openTooltipDialog("#{id:tooltipDialog1}",'#{id:button1}')`

How does it work on SSJS? If a function returns false, this tooltip dialog has to appear next to the button. I believe this tooltip should be close to the button.
It appears bottom left corner

All these commands below don't work:

```
facesContext.getViewRoot().postScript("XSP.openTooltipDialog('#{id:tooltipDialog1}')");

facesContext.getViewRoot().postScript("XSP.openTooltipDialog('#{id:tooltipDialog1}','#{id:button20}')");

view.postScript("XSP.openTooltipDialog('#{id:tooltipDialog1}');");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `getComponent("tooltipDialog1").show()`. The syntax for opening tooltip dialogs in SSJS is the same as for normal dialogs, see XPages Extension Library pp156-162.

setFor() is available via SSJS only.

[image]

Comment: If i use this command above tooltip dialog appears buttom left not near the button.  :( I think i need to define element ID for tooltipDialog. (like ,'#{id:button20}')")

Comment: p161, the TooltipDialog component has a `setFor()` method to determine the component (using its server-side ID) to which it should be attached.

Comment: I am sorry but i couldn't find the property you mentioned. :( is it possible to send me a screen shot or could you please tell me how i can find it?

Comment: It's not a property available in All Properties, it's a method available via SSJS. I've added a screenshot of methods specifically added over and above the UIDialog class to my answer.

Comment: Paul If you don't mind please show me the way of UIDialog Class how to reach in Domino Designer. I don't want to to disturb you but I couldn't find the menu links you mentioned above in screen shot. :(

Comment: Calling `getComponent()` on a Tooltip Dialog will get the component. It's class is `UITooltipDialog`. That screenshot is from the Extension Library source code.

Comment: Unless you use the Control Declaration Snippets on Reference tab of the SSJS Script editor or case the SSJS variable to the specific class (`getClass().getName()` gives that), you only get generic methods in typeahead, because the editor doesn't know what type of component it is.

Comment: It should be worked like this? am i right?
var c = getComponent("tooltipDialog1");
c.setFor("fieldName");
c.show();

Comment: I have added a screenshot top of this page. You can see how it works. I mean It does not work :(

Comment: Then you will need to raise a defect on the project here https://github.com/OpenNTF/XPagesExtensionLibrary/issues